# Echo results out in 3 columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

**I am trying to make my results from my database to be echo'ed out in 3 columns like this.**

result 1     result 2     result 3

result 4     result 5     result 6

And so on..

*This is my HTML code:*

```
<div class="grid1">

    <div class="box">

    </div><!-- box -->

</div><!-- grid1 -->

<div class="grid2">

    <div class="box">

    </div><!-- box -->

</div><!-- grid2 -->

<div class="grid3">

    <div class="box">

    </div><!-- box -->

</div><!-- grid3 -->
```

So I am figuering out how to make the while loop?

Comment: You do realise that HTML is only used for Markup , right?. What you need is back-end code and a whole lot of web development tutorials.

Comment: Yes, i used css to make the grid and style the boxes, but i can't figure out how to show it in 3 colums. Maybe 3 while loops? :P

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/crjocbvh/1/

Comment: I would recommend having one loop, with a counter variable that counts from 1 to 3 and then resets to 1. Then create three arrays, and sequentially add each of your db results to an array, using the counter. Then you can display the contents of each array inside of it's respective column.

Comment: Oh thanks Blake! That was just the solution I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly elegant code, but let's try it anyway. The core here is to iterate through the array, and whenever the array element MOD 3 is zero (i.e. we've hit every third element), we start a new row.

Something like this:

```
$arr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G');
echo "<table><tr>"
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
     $item = arr[$i];
     echo "<td>" . $item . "</td>";
     if ($i % 3 == 0) {
         echo "</tr></tr>";
     } 
}
echo "</tr></table>"
```